# an error occurs after GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns, error number is ERROR_INVALID_NETNAME

Tags: iocp

GetQueuedCompletionStatus fails with ERROR_INVALID_NETNAME.  What does this mean?  I tried looking in MSDN.

First step: connect to the server using [ConnectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  [ConnectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) succeeds, with error code 997 (ERROR_IO_PENDING):

```
DWORD bytes = 0;
sockaddr_in addr = {0};
iocp_data_t * iocp = (iocp_data_t *)module->data;

addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ip;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);

if(!iocp->tcp_connectex(event->fd, (const sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in),
                        NULL, 0, NULL, &event->connect.overlap))
{
    if(!ERR_RW_RETRIABLE(socket_geterror(event->fd)))
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

[GetQueuedCompletionStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns after the [ConnectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call finishes, but with error code 1214 (ERROR_INVALID_NETNAME):

```
fd_event_t * fd_event;
iocp_data_t * iocp = (iocp_data_t *)module->data;

rc = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp->iocp, &bytes, (PULONG_PTR)&fd_event,
                               (LPOVERLAPPED *) &event, (u_long) 1);
if(event == NULL)
{
    return;
}
DWORD err = GetLastError(); // err = 1214
event = containing_record(event,event_t,overlap);
if(event->in_used)
{
    if(event->event_handler != NULL)
    {
        event->event_handler(module,fd_event,event->type,event->user);
    }
    iocp_add_event(module,fd_event,event->type,event->event_handler,event->user);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `ERROR_INVALID_NETNAME` is not an error code that `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` can report. Please show a real example.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to check:

- Where does `ip` come from?  You might need to use [htonl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- How is the socket created?  Perhaps your particular socket can't deal with IPv4 addresses (e.g. it's an IPv6 socket).

Also, make sure [GetQueuedCompletionStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns FALSE before calling [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  [GetQueuedCompletionStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has three possible outcomes:

- Return value of TRUE:

  Completion packet dequeued successfully, and the I/O finished successfully.
- Return value of FALSE, with the OVERLAPPED set to NULL:

  GetQueuedCompletionStatus itself failed to dequeue a completion (e.g. timed out).
- Return value of FALSE, with the OVERLAPPED not NULL:

  Completion packet dequeued, but the I/O it represents failed.